# How to validate rich text editor source

Tags: php, html, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I am using [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) in my application for rich text that the user will fill in.

When I validate the textarea element in my PHP server side script, I do all the checking e.g. if the element is empty.

There is a problem with this in that the source of the text editor sometimes remains despite the text being cleared.

Here is an example of what I mean:

Say I have a rich text editor as shown below and I have the heading 'write your first page!'.

[image]

Here is how the source looks for the above picture:
[image]

Then when I remove the text only and NOT any empty lines remaining, the source around the text remains as shown below:

[image]

The PHP `empty` function is going not going to pass as it's technically not empty because of the source code contained in the text editor.

The issue with this is I cannot rely on the user to clear the whole screen including empty lines, so is there a way I can get rid of any source that doesn't contain actual content as the second image above shows?

HTML:

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="chapter"><h4 style="text-align: center;">Write your first page!</h4></textarea>
```

Comment: sorry but i really think this is real correct user entry. You may know if value is empty or not but you don't know if its html tags are empty. I think its not posibble without parse html entry

Comment: you may see .. the editor doesn't  know too. If he has known html tag is empty, he removed it

Comment: Yes, user entry is fine but the problem is the html tags. If I do `if(empty($_POST['chapter']){...}` with the above, it will always return false because it contains html tags but no actual content within them. So is there a way around that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood well your problem, you want to know if there is some text or just HTML tags.

In PHP, you can do the follow:

```
$text = trim(strip_tags($chapter));
if ($text == ''){
   // just HTML tags
}
```

The [strip_tags](https://php.net/strip_tags) function removes the HTML tags.

The trim function remove white spaces, break lines, etc...

Comment: Yes! `strip_tags` did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Mind that this will say that the editor is "empty" if it contains only nontextual HTML data. An image, for instance.

Comment: @duskwuff I could use the optional second parameter to allow certain tags 

e.g. `strip_tags($chapter,"<img>")`